# What are some alternatives to the Content Query Web Part for displaying list data in a custom layout?

Tags: 2010, list-view, content-query-web-part

I have some very specific requirements for displaying data from a List of Announcements.  The Content Query Web Part can do almost what I need but does not seem like a very effecient solution.  Modifying the ItemStyle.xslt everytime I want to employ a new layout of the data seems very cumbersome.  Are there alternatives that would give better control for layout of the data?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a data view web part, that would give you total control over the output and layout.

You could use REST or ASMX web services to fetch the data and then style it as desired.

You could use Search and fetch the data and style the results as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed Item Lister & Item Viewer Web Parts for these kind of situations. You can check them out at: http://www.spwp.net

Have a nice day...